# How to convert method passed arguments into one object in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameters, arguments, args

There is Jax-Ws web service method which gets 20 argument. arguments should be validated, so I have to pass all of them to another validator method separately or create class object by passing arguments to constructor and then use this object to call validator method

Here is an example

**WebService interface object**

```
public interface IEcommWs {
    @WebMethod
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "payment", className = "ge.jibo.ecomm.ws.wrapper.PaymentRequest")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "paymentResponse", className = "ge.jibo.ecomm.ws.wrapper.PaymentResponse")
    public void payment(@WebParam(name = "requestType", mode = Mode.IN) RequestType requestType,
            @WebParam(name = "merchantId", mode = Mode.IN) String merchantId,
            .... another 20 param ....
            @WebParam(name = "response", mode = Mode.OUT) Holder<Response> response,
            @WebParam(name = "paymentResult", mode = Mode.OUT) Holder<PaymentResult> paymentResult);
}
```

**and the implementation**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ge.jibo.ecomm.ws.IEcommWs")
public class EcommWs implements IEcommWs {

    @Override
    public void payment(RequestType requestType, String merchantId, 
            .... another 20 param ....
            Holder<Response> response,
            Holder<PaymentResult> paymentResult) {

        Validator.validateInput(RequestType requestType, String merchantId, .... another 20 param ....);

        or 
        PaymentRequest requestParams = new PaymentRequest(RequestType requestType, String merchantId, .... another 20 param ....);

        Validator.validateInput(requestParams);
    }
```

Can I convert all this arguments in one object without using class constructor?

like this

```
PaymentRequest requestParams = getPaymentMethodParams();
```